# Displaying how many times a button has been clicked

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, button

I have created a button in HTML and I want to know how I can use Vue.js to  display in the console how many times it has been pressed at.

This is what I have done so far:

```
<div class="123">
  <button id = "Abutton" @click="abutton()">
    <img src="randomimage.png"
         style="width: 30px; height: 30px;"
    />
  </button>
</div>
```

And in Vue.js:

```
abutton: function (e) {
  const ButtonVal = e.target.value;
  console.log("Number of likes:" + ButtonVal)
},
```

Comment: You have nothing here holding the value of the button clicks.  If you are using the options API, you need to add a`data` property (call it `clickCount`) and increment that in your function `abutton` and then print `clickCount`.

Answer (score 0):

A `button` has no `value`... But you could use a data attribute like this:

```
<div class="123">
  <button id = "Abutton" @click="abutton()" data-clickcount="0">
    <img src="randomimage.png"
         style="width: 30px; height: 30px;"
    />
  </button>
</div>
```

And in Vue.js:

```
abutton: function (e) {
  // Get the count
  const ButtonVal = +(e.target.dataset.clickcount);
  // Increment and store it
  e.target.dataset.clickcount = ButtonVal++;
  // log it
  console.log("Number of likes:" + ButtonVal)
},
```